# Implementing fictional calendar formats

Tags: c#, calendar

I am working on a project in WPF using MVVM in which I would like to use a fictional calendar. I would like the year to be 100 days long and just be broken up into 2 seasons instead of months. As far as I can tell, `DateTime` can't do this and I'm having some trouble implementing it myself (primarily I think my approach is far from ideal). Any advice you could give me that would help get this working would be greatly appreciated.

```
public enum Season { Dry, Rainy }
public class Date : ObservableObject
{
    #region Members

    private int _year;
    private int _dayOfYear;
    private Season _season;
    private string _displayDate;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int Year
    {
        get { return _year; }
        set { _year = value; }
    }

    public int DayOfYear
    {
        get { return _dayOfYear; }
        set 
        {
            if (_dayOfYear == value)
                return;
            _dayOfYear = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => DayOfYear);
        }
    }

    public Season Season
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dayOfYear < 70)
                return Models.Season.Dry;
            else
                return Models.Season.Rainy;
        }
        set { _season = value; }
    }

    public string DisplayDate
    {
        get
        {
            return (_dayOfYear.ToString() + " Season of " + _season.ToString() + " " + _year.ToString());
        }
        set
        {
            if (_displayDate == value)
                return;
            _displayDate = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => DisplayDate);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

---

In the viewmodel:

```
public string Date
{
    get { return DataManager.Data.Date.DisplayDate; }
    set
    {
        if (DataManager.Data.Date.DisplayDate == value)
            return;
        DataManager.Data.Date.DisplayDate = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Date);
    }
}
```

The UI will display the string but never update it. When I update the date, the "DayOfYear" setter fires but that's all that happens.

I would imagine that this is not a very good way to go about this. If anybody has an MVVM-friendly way to implement a custom calendar style, I would love to learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that internally you use an `int` to represent the day. For every day, increment the value by 1. Then, to compute the year, you have:

```
int year = day/100;
```

And the season:

```
Season season = (day % 100) < 70 ? Season.Dry : Season.Rainy;
```

It would look something like this:

```
public class MyCustomDate
{
    private int _day;

    public int Year
    {
        get { return _day / 100; }
    }

    public Season Season
    {
        get { return (DayOfYear < 70) ? Season.Dry : Season.Rainy; }
    }

    public int DayOfYear
    {
        get { return _day % 100; }
    }

    // Create a date, given the year and the day within the year.
    public MyCustomDate(int year, int day)
    {
        _day = (100 * year) + day;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}, {2}", DayOfYear, Season, Year);
    }
}
```

You could add other properties and methods to compute the difference between two dates, create a date from a day, season, and year, add days to a date, etc. The key is to do all of your calculations in days. Only use season and year for input and output.

I would suggest that you make your custom class immutable. If you make it mutable (i.e. you can set the `Season`, for example), then you have to add a whole lot of verification code. Consider the date of `55 Dry 2012`. If you change the season to `Rainy`, you have an invalid date because there are only 30 days in the rainy season. The same kind of thing happens if you try to set the day larger than 99. You're better off doing all of that validation in constructors.

Not saying that you can't have property setters, just that I wouldn't recommend it. But I suppose an immutable type might give you trouble with observable? I don't know enough about observable to say.

Comment: This looks like the direction I need to take in this situation. Now I just need to figure out how to get the binding in the UI to work.

Comment: This has some holes (for example, on the 100th day it will read Year 2 Day 0), but it seems to be closest to what I need so I'll go ahead and accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JasonD: Change the `DayOfYear` calculation to `return (_day % 100)+1;`

Comment: Doing that and changing the starting day to 0 seems to make it function properly. Thanks for your help. I certainly do appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the reason you don't see the display value change is because in the getter of `DisplayDate`, you don't use the `_displayDate` value at all.  So you are changing the `_displayDate`, and then raising that the property changed, but then it just retrieves the same string that it did before.

That being said, there are some fundamentals that you need to consider:

- In just about any language or platform, and *especially* in .Net, date and time types are implemented as value types.  They are immutable structs.  Your implementation is designed as a mutable, observable class.  This is asking for trouble, as you will be probably passing them around with value type semantics.
- Besides just being a container of fields, it's also important that the values are sortable.  That requires implementing `IComparable`.  It also means that there is usually one single field behind the scenes.  For example, `DateTime` has only a single field which is internally a 64-bit integer.
- There's a lot more to consider if you are trying to implement the concept of a "calendar system".  For example, you say a year is 100 days long, but you don't implement that anywhere.  And what is the basis of your years?  Are you defining an epoch?  How would one convert from a known calendar such as the ISO8601 or Gregorian calendar systems?  Do days break down into other sizes, such as weeks?  Do you have "time zones" or does everyone just use the same basis, such as UTC?  Can I parse your format from a string?  There are many others.

If you actually want to implement a custom calendar system.  There are two routes you could go:

- Extend [`System.Globalization.Calendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82aak18x.aspx) - Not very good in general, but might get the job done.
- Extend [`NodaTime.CalendarSystem`](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.1.x/docs/api/html/T_NodaTime_CalendarSystem.htm) - This is a much better idea, but you will need to learn a lot to get started.  Most of [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) is focused around the ISO calendar.  You may need to ask questions on [the Noda Time mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/noda-time).